# How do I pass data from an input field into my database (Parse) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass the email and password obtained from someone signing up (html below)

```
<form id="frm-signup">
      <h5>Email</h5>
      <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
      <h5>Password</h5>
      <input id="register-password" type="password" name="password" />
   /*Pass data*/
      <% users = User.new %>
      <% users.username = @email %>
      <% users.password = @password %>
      <% users.save %>
</form>
```

and pass it into my database, but I cant quite seem to figure it out. I may just be combining several different methods? I am new to Ruby and am still figuring things out.

**My User Model:**

```
class User < ParseUser
  fields :email, :password, :firstName, :lastName
  validates_presence_of :email, :password
  alias :email :username
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 8, :allow_blank => false

  has_many :items, :primary_key => "objectId"
end
```

**My UserController:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

    @email = params[:email].nil? 1; params[:email]
    @username = params[:email].nil? 1; params[:email]
    @password = params[:password].nil? 1; params[:password]

    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "logged in !"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid username or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def index

  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

Regarding saving in the database, since your user model is inheriting from ParseUser, there should be a ParseUser method that would allow you to save. So, you would call `User.save(username,password)` (that's not actually the method, rather it would be something like that in parse), and that would save in the database.

Also, some general advice: If you are new to rails, working with something like Parse is probably making things more difficult for you. Go do one of the many rails tutorials (I recommend railstutorial.org) that teach you the basics, and after you understand the basics, move onto more complex things.

Comment: That didn't quite work, but I'm certain it's the way I've written the code. The tutorial helped. Thanks!